# Как обновить пакет (mpdf) через composer в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, composer

В моём проекте на yii2 стоит `mPDF v7.1.6` , этот пакет не работает под `php 7.3`, 7.3 поддерживается со следующей версии,  `mPDF v >= 7.1.7`.

Не хочется менять версию `php` на более старую
Как через `composer` обновить этот пакет, так чтобы ничего не сломалось?

Answer (score 0):

```
composer update mpdf/mpdf
```

Конечно, чтобы ничего не сломалось нужно тестировать.